# Types of numbers.

Tags: soft-question, big-list

Is there a comprehensive list of real-number-describers that allude to the properties of that number? 
For example: 
Amicable numbers, Abundant, Deficient, Perfect, Carmichael, prime, transcendental, etc.

1. If so, where can I find it? 
2. What are some new, exciting types of numbers with interesting properties? 
3. What is *name* of the *type*  of irrational number that contains every natural number as a substring of its decimal expansion ?

Comment: for three: normal

Comment: for two: liouville

Comment: @user58512, all normal numbers satisfy 3, but not all numbers that satisfy 3 have to be normal.

Comment: I wouldn't say the Liouville numbers are a *new* type, as asked in 2.  After all, Liouville has been dead for over a century.

Comment: for three: "disjunctive number" and "rich number in base 10" seem to be somewhat in use at present.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thx. Your comment was useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wikipedia provides a solid list of numbers: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_numbers

Comment: This is a good list, @Jeremy Thank you. I do feel like there are more than this list has though.

Comment: @Rustyn Yazdanpour: Some that might not be on that list (I haven't checked) can be found by googling ["transcendence measure" number](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22transcendence+measure%22+number), ["computable real number"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22computable+real+number%22), ["pythagorean constructible"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22pythagorean+constructible%22), ["explicit algebraic number"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22explicit+algebraic+number%22), and ["closed form number"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22closed+form+number%22).

Answer (score 1):

For 3, the general type is a [normal number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number), though this is more restrictive than your request.  These will have all sequences present in the proper proportion.  The specific one $0.123456789101112131415161718 \ldots$ is known as Champernowne's constant

Comment: Hey thanks for your contribution, @Ross